# Binding multiple application.yml from working directory to ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Starting with Spring Boot 2.4.0, from what I gather from [the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-files-wildcards), I should be able to bind multiple `application.yaml` files from the working directory to `ConfigurationProperties`:

> Wildcard locations are particularly useful in an environment such as Kubernetes when there are multiple sources of config properties.

> For example, if you have some Redis configuration and some MySQL configuration, you might want to keep those two pieces of configuration separate, while requiring that both those are present in an application.properties file. This might result in two separate application.properties files mounted at different locations such as /config/redis/application.properties and /config/mysql/application.properties. In such a case, having a wildcard location of config/*/, will result in both files being processed.

> By default, Spring Boot includes config/*/ in the default search locations. The means that all subdirectories of the /config directory outside of your jar will be searched.

It is my understanding that the following test case shows that this does not work as described:

Project hierarchy:

```
config/
  first/
    application.yaml
  second/
    application.yaml
src/
  main/
    kotlin/
      test/
        Application.kt
  test/
    kotlin/
      test/
        TestCase.kt
```

`config/first/application.yaml`

```yaml
composite:
  from-first-file:
    it: works
```

`config/second/application.yaml`

```yaml
composite:
  from-second-file:
    it: works
```

`src/main/kotlin/test/Application.kt`

```kt
@SpringBootApplication(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CompositeProperties::class)
class Application

fun main(vararg args: String) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}

@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("composite")
data class CompositeProperties(
    val fromFirstFile: Map<String, String> = mapOf(),
    val fromSecondFile: Map<String, String> = mapOf()
)
```

`src/test/kotlin/test/TestCase.kt`

```kt
@SpringBootTest
class TestCase {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var compositeProperties: CompositeProperties

    @Test
    fun `first file is bound to configuration properties`() {
        assertThat(compositeProperties.fromFirstFile).containsEntry("it", "works")
    }

    @Test
    fun `second file is bound to configuration properties`() {
        assertThat(compositeProperties.fromSecondFile).containsEntry("it", "works")
    }
}
```

The first test passes, the second one fails. I tried several variations to rule out edge cases and it looks like the second file is completely overlooked. For instance, I tried setting the `spring.application.name` in the second file and it is not taken into account either.

If this is indeed a bug, is there a workaround I could use until this is fixed?

Comment: Can you try `config` directory inside `/src/main`?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but could the behaviour be due to spring not merging property trees. ie. if you had two `ConfigurationProperties` classes that loaded different base level yaml trees - composite1 and composite2 does that work?

Comment: config should be in the directory next to your jar file as you aren't running a jar file this rule doesn't apply.

Comment: @Steephen I could, but what would be the point, since it's not my requirement at all? Anyway, nothing gets bound when doing what you suggest

Comment: @HopeyOne As mentioned in the OP, I tried adding a different property to the second file and it isn't bound either, so that should give us a solid hint that your suggestion won't work; and indeed, it doesn't

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you please enlighten me with arguments that support your claim?

Comment: The documentation that you yourself quoted. **By default, Spring Boot includes config/*/ in the default search locations. The means that all subdirectories of the /config directory outside of your jar will be searched.**. Your config location isn't in one of the default search locations.

Comment: You over-interpret this part of the sentence. This doesn't work from within a JAR either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, this is [a bug in 2.4.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24428). Until the problem is fixed, it can be worked around by setting `spring.config.use-legacy-processing=true`.